# How do I generate multiple images and put them into one zip file for download using Rails3?

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, download, zip

I am generating QR codes from Google's charting API on my website as a URL with some params passed in.

I have around 100 of these codes which are generated from a URL, something like this:

```
$= image_tag("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=#{qr.code}&chs=120x120&choe=UTF-8", :size => "120x120")
```

I want to create a method that loops through my array and generates the png files, then places them inside a zip file which I can download from one click.

I tried using `send_data "url", :disposition = > "attachment", :type => "image/png"`

This only saved the URL, not the image generated. Putting the URL into the browser opened a window with the image.

Other than that I was not able to add all the files into a zip file. Does Rails have its own built-in compression methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, for each QR code, use [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) to download the QR code's image from Google's API into a temp file. Then use [rubyzip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) to compress the temp files into a zip file.  An example of how to use the zip library is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471407/set-compression-level-when-generating-a-zip-file-using-rubyzip/2722425#2722425). Finally, use `send_data` (or `send_file` if you've written it to disk) to send this generated zip file to the client's web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my mod_zip module for Nginx:

https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip

You can dynamically stream a ZIP file to the client without any temporary files.